# unable to deploy data in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent

**problem**: I set point breaks at the following code:

```
 intent.putExtra(WorkoutRoutinesActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_NAME, workoutName);
 intent.putExtra(WorkoutRoutinesActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_DAYS, workoutDays);
```

, both showed up as null when I ran the app in debug mode. `workoutName` contains a simple String that is passed to a new activity, whereas `workoutDays` constains an array of String.

the full code is provided below:

```
public class CreateWorkoutActivity extends Activity {


public final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
protected String[] workoutDays = new String[7];
protected String workoutName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_workout);

     Button mNextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next_button1);
     CheckBox satBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sat_checkbox);
     CheckBox sunBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sun_checkbox);
     CheckBox monBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.mon_checkbox);
     CheckBox tuesBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tues_checkbox);
     CheckBox wedBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.wed_checkbox);
     CheckBox thursBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.thurs_checkbox);
     CheckBox friBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fri_checkbox);

    final EditText mWorkoutName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workout_name1);
    workoutName = mWorkoutName.getText().toString();

    Log.i(TAG, workoutName);



   if (satBox.isChecked()) {
      workoutDays[0] = new String(satBox.getText().toString());
   }

    if (sunBox.isChecked()) {
        workoutDays[1] = new String(sunBox.getText().toString());
    }

    if (monBox.isChecked()) {
        workoutDays[2] =  new String(monBox.getText().toString());
    }

    if (tuesBox.isChecked()) {
        workoutDays[3] = new String(tuesBox.getText().toString());
    }

    if (wedBox.isChecked()) {
        workoutDays[4] =  wedBox.getText().toString();
    }

    if (thursBox.isChecked()) {
        workoutDays[5] =  satBox.getText().toString();
    }

    if (friBox.isChecked()) {
        workoutDays[6] = friBox.getText().toString();
        Log.i(TAG, workoutDays[6]);
    }




    mNextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i(TAG, workoutDays.toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(CreateWorkoutActivity.this, WorkoutRoutinesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(WorkoutRoutinesActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_NAME, workoutName);
            intent.putExtra(WorkoutRoutinesActivity.EXTRA_WORKOUT_DAYS, workoutDays);
            Log.i(TAG, workoutDays.toString());
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: show us how you retrieve the date from the other activity.

Comment: Hi, I would post the code, but the problem is in this activity(i.e. all the data input in intent is appearing as null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not in the intent, but in the way you obtain `workoutName` (this is the null value). You create the activity, set up `final EditText mWorkoutName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.workout_name1);` and then immediately ask for the input value through `workoutName = mWorkoutName.getText().toString();`, but at this time the user still hasn't entered anything. You should put that second line in the listener below (so its activated only after the user presses mNextButton. It's a good idea to put some check after it and send a message to user that they need to fill in that field (if it is indeed necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the values for `workoutName` and `workoutDays` are not filled in initially when the view is created. You should move retrieving the value from the text fields to your `onClickListener` function.

Answer (score 1):

you checking the CheckBox and EditText in onCreate, absolutely the EditText will be empty and all CheckBox it not checked